# Extract content of code which start with a curly bracket and ends with a curly bracket followed by closing parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm completely mess with Regular Expressions right now(lack of practice).
I'm writing a node script, which goes through a bunch of js files, each file calls a function, with one of the arguments being a json. The aim is to get all those json arguments and place them in one file. The problem I'm facing at the moment is the extraction of the argument part of the code, here is the function call part of that string:

```
$translateProvider.translations('de', {
        WASTE_MANAGEMENT: 'Abfallmanagement',
        WASTE_TYPE_LIST: 'Abfallarten',
        WASTE_ENTRY_LIST: 'Abfalleinträge',
        WASTE_TYPE: 'Abfallart',
        TREATMENT_TYPE: 'Behandlungsart',
        TREATMENT_TYPE_STATUS: 'Status Behandlungsart',
        DUPLICATED_TREATMENT_TYPE: 'Doppelte Behandlungsart',
        TREATMENT_TYPE_LIST: 'Behandlungsarten',
        TREATMENT_TARGET_LIST: 'Ziele Behandlungsarten',
        TREATMENT_TARGET_ADD: 'Ziel Behandlungsart hinzufügen',
        SITE_TARGET: 'Gebäudeziel',
        WASTE_TREATMENT_TYPES: 'Abfallbehandlungsarten',
        WASTE_TREATMENT_TARGETS: '{{Abfallbehandlungsziele}}',
        WASTE_TREATMENT_TYPES_LIST: '{{Abfallbehandlungsarten}}',
        WASTE_TYPE_ADD: 'Abfallart hinzufügen',
        UNIT_ADD: 'Einheit hinzufügen'
})
```

So I'm trying to write a regular expression which matches the segment of the js code, which starts with *"'de', {"* and ends with *"})"*, while it can have any characters between(single/double curly brackets included).
I tried something like this `\'de'\s*,\s*{([^}]*)})\` , but that doesn't work. The furthest I got was with this `\'de'\s*,\s*{([^})]*)}\` , but this ends at the first closing curly bracket within the json, which is not what I want.
It seems, that even the concepts of regular exressions I understood before, now I completely forgot.
Any is help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output of your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with lookahead, lookbehind, and boundary-type assertions:

```
/(?<=^\$translateProvider\.translations\('de', {)[\s\S]*(?=}\)$)/
```

- `(?<=^\$translateProvider\.translations\('de', {)` is a lookbehind assertion that checks for `'$translateProvider.translations('de', {'` at the beginning of the string.
- `(?=}\)$)` is a lookahead assertion that checks for `'})'` at the end of the string.
- `[\s\S]*` is a character class that matches any sequence of space and non-space characters between the two assertions.

[Here is the regex101 link for you to test](https://regex101.com/r/2mABJj/1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the issue. I had to play around with the possible white space caused by indentation, but it definitely saved me a lot of time. I think I will spend some time with having a look on how these lookahead and lookbehind work exactly. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. The MDN regexp cheat sheet is a great resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet

Comment: Sorry for coming back on this, but I'm  just one small issue here:
So I passed the regular expression given to a RegExp constructor, it looks like this `code`     var regExp = new RegExp('(?<=^\\s+\\$translateProvider\\.translations\\(\'' + lang + '\',\\s*{)[\\s\\S]*(?=}\\);$)', 'gm'); `code` . Now the issue is, that in some cases the .translations method can be in a new line. I know that I can check for new lines with something like this [\n\r]* , but it seems, that some of the special character not getting escaped correctly, I tried it this way \\[\\n\\r\\]*, but it fails.

Comment: use the multiline flag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline#description

Answer (score 2):

You did not state the desired output. Here is a solution that parses the text, and creates an array of arrays. You can easily transform that to a desired output.

```js
const input = `$translateProvider.translations('de', {
        WASTE_MANAGEMENT: 'Abfallmanagement',
        WASTE_TYPE_LIST: 'Abfallarten',
        WASTE_ENTRY_LIST: 'Abfalleinträge',
        WASTE_TYPE: 'Abfallart',
        TREATMENT_TYPE: 'Behandlungsart',
        TREATMENT_TYPE_STATUS: 'Status Behandlungsart',
        DUPLICATED_TREATMENT_TYPE: 'Doppelte Behandlungsart',
        TREATMENT_TYPE_LIST: 'Behandlungsarten',
        TREATMENT_TARGET_LIST: 'Ziele Behandlungsarten',
        TREATMENT_TARGET_ADD: 'Ziel Behandlungsart hinzufügen',
        SITE_TARGET: 'Gebäudeziel',
        WASTE_TREATMENT_TYPES: 'Abfallbehandlungsarten',
        WASTE_TREATMENT_TARGETS: '{{Abfallbehandlungsziele}}',
        WASTE_TREATMENT_TYPES_LIST: '{{Abfallbehandlungsarten}}',
        WASTE_TYPE_ADD: 'Abfallart hinzufügen',
        UNIT_ADD: 'Einheit hinzufügen'
})`;

const regex1 = /\.translations\([^{]*\{\s+(.*?)\s*\}\)/s;
const regex2 = /',[\r\n]+\s*/;
const regex3 = /: +'/;
let result = [];
let m = input.match(regex1);
if(m) {
  result = m[1].split(regex2).map(line => line.split(regex3));
}
console.log(result);
```

Explanation of `regex1`:

- `\.translations\(` -- literal `.translations(`
- `[^{]*` -- anything not `{`
- `\{\s+` -- `{` and all whitespace
- `(.*?)` -- capture group 1 with non-greedy scan up to:
- `\s*\}\)` -- whitespace, followed by `})`
- `s` flag to make `.` match newlines

Explanation of `regex2`:

- `',[\r\n]+\s*` -- `',`, followed by newlines and space (to split lines)

Explanation of `regex3`:

- `: +'` -- literal `: '` (to split key/value)

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: Hi Peter, while your answer does indeed returns the keys and values grouped together, I'd still have to do some iteration to get the result I need. The previous answer seems to be extracting the exact part of the code, which I need. Thank you for your time and the documentation link you added, I will try to go through and get a better understanding of more advanced regular expressions(even memorize them). Although I cannot mark it as the answer to the question, but your solution does deserve a vote, as it is valid. I'm pretty sure it will be useful for people with similar issue. Thanks again.